# How to have multiple imports under a same variable

Tags: javascript, browserify

I want to organize my project imports with browserify so that I have a global utils variable from which I can call and execute functions much like jquery's `$`.

So in the end I want something like:

```
window.utils = ...
```

So I can use utils.aFunction();

I also want to divide my dependencies in several files, as an example, this would be my project:

```
libs
  |_ math.js //Implements randomInt and RandomFloat methods
  |_ connection.js //Implements isConnected method
utils.js //Calls all the required dependencies
```

My idea so far is to have something like this:

In `libs/math.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    randInt: function() {
        return 4;
    },
    randFloat: function() {
        return 4.1;
    }
};
```

And then I would do in `utils.js`:

```
var math = require('./libs/math');
var connection = require('./libs/connection');

var libs = [math, connection];

var utils = {};

for (var i = 0; i < libs.length; i++) {
    for (var key in libs[i]) {
        utils[key] = libs[i][key];
    }
}

window.utils = utils;
```

This actually works just fine, but I don't know if it wasn't already solved by a library.

I have a feeling there are more efficient ways of doing this, what would be the recommended approach with browserify?

Answer (score 0):

The code for throwing things into util object is definitely odd looking, and I wouldn't recommend this looping over all your required util submodules.

```
var libs = [math, connection];

var utils = {};

for (var i = 0; i < libs.length; i++) {
  for (var key in libs[i]) {
    utils[key] = libs[i][key];
  }
}
```

If you were using a common js approach with webpack/browserify, you would simply declare your util to be global in the configuration file, and simply add the needed module.exports inside of your util.js

```
//connect.js
  module.exports = {
    isConnected: function(){
        return true;
    }
};
//math.js
module.exports = {
    randInt: function() {
        return 4;
    },
    randFloat: function() {
        return 4.1;
    }
};
//utils.js
exports.math = require('./math');
exports.connect = require('./connect');
//test.js
var utils = require('./utils');
console.log(utils.math.randInt());
console.log(utils.connect.isConnected());
```